# MySQL - Time difference between rows of the same type

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a list of agent_ids, a previous_status, a new status, and a time stamp.  I'm trying to determine the time difference between each status change, by agent, in order to determine how long an agent was active in a particular status.

For example:

```
+------+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| id   |  agent_id    |   old_status |   new_status   |  date_time           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1   |      1       |     offline  |      online    |  2015-06-11 09:00:01 |
|  2   |      1       |     online   |      busy      |  2015-06-11 09:30:23 |
|  3   |      3       |     offline  |      online    |  2015-06-11 09:31:27 |
|  4   |      1       |     busy     |      offline   |  2015-06-11 09:31:45 |
|  5   |      3       |     online   |      offline   |  2015-06-11 09:32:10 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The goal would be to create a new result table with a time_difference column,
and the time_difference column for row 5 for example, should be 43 seconds, which is the difference between row 5 (the  most recent status for agent_id 3) and row 3, the previous status for agent_id 3. Likewise, the time_difference for row 4 should be difference between row 4 and row 2.

Comment: how about a schema change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of

```
SELECT id, agent_id, old_status, new_status, date_time, seconds
  FROM
(
SELECT id, agent_id, old_status, new_status, date_time, 
       IF(@a = agent_id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @p, date_time), NULL) seconds,
       @a := agent_id, @p := date_time
  FROM table1 t CROSS JOIN (SELECT @p := NULL, @a := NULL) i
 ORDER BY agent_id, id
) q
```

Output:

```
+------+----------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------+
| id   | agent_id | old_status | new_status | date_time           | seconds |
+------+----------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------+
|    1 |        1 | offline    | online     | 2015-06-11 09:00:01 |    NULL |
|    2 |        1 | online     | busy       | 2015-06-11 09:30:23 |    1822 |
|    4 |        1 | busy       | offline    | 2015-06-11 09:31:45 |      82 |
|    3 |        3 | offline    | online     | 2015-06-11 09:31:27 |    NULL |
|    5 |        3 | online     | offline    | 2015-06-11 09:32:10 |      43 |
+------+----------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecd57/1)** demo

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!  The only little issue I'm having now is that when you get the difference between a status today vs. the status yesterday, its of course giving a huge amount of time, for example 18 hours of time.  Well, since these events are happening during an 8-5 work day usually, I only want to compare time difference during each day, and not the first event today with the last event yesterday.  Is there any way to only compare differences in statuses on the same day?

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this without variables, using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       timestampdiff(second, t.date_time, t.next_date_time) as secs
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.date_time
              from table t2
              where t2.agent_id = t.agent_id and
                    t2.date_time > t.date_time
              order by t2.date_time
              limit 1
             ) as next_date_time
      from table t
     ) t
```