# Get difference between time of next record MySQL Large dataset

Tags: mysql

I am having some trouble with the following, fairly simple, query.

Sample data:

```
+-------+------+-------+---------------------+
| f_rec | f_id | REF   | ORI_TIME            |
+-------+------+-------+---------------------+
|     1 |    1 | 20784 | 1899-12-30 11:03:18 |
|     2 |    1 | 20785 | 1899-12-30 11:03:27 |
|     3 |    1 | 20786 | 1899-12-30 11:03:28 |
|     4 |    1 | 20787 | 1899-12-30 11:03:38 |
|     5 |    1 | 20788 | 1899-12-30 11:03:45 |
|     6 |    1 | 20789 | 1899-12-30 11:03:52 |
|     7 |    2 | 50790 | 1899-12-30 11:04:09 |
|     8 |    2 | 50791 | 1899-12-30 11:04:26 |
|     9 |    2 | 50792 | 1899-12-30 11:05:27 |
|    10 |    2 | 50793 | 1899-12-30 11:05:38 |
+-------+------+-------+---------------------+
```

Query:

```
 SELECT IDfocCurr.f_rec, IDfocCurr.f_id,
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, IDfocCurr.ORI_TIME, 
        (SELECT IDfocNext.ORI_TIME 
        FROM IDfocals1999-2004 IDfocNext 
        WHERE IDfocNext.REF = IDfocCurr.REF + 1 
            AND IDfocCurr.f_id = IDfocNext.f_id )) as DURATION_NEW,
       FROM IDfocals1999-2004 IDfocCurr
```

Desired result:

```
+-------+------+-------+---------------------+-------------+
| f_rec | f_id | REF   | ORI_TIME            |DURATION_NEW |
+-------+------+-------+---------------------+-------------+
|     1 |    1 | 20784 | 1899-12-30 11:03:18 |            9|
|     2 |    1 | 20785 | 1899-12-30 11:03:27 |            1|
|     3 |    1 | 20786 | 1899-12-30 11:03:28 |           10|
|     4 |    1 | 20787 | 1899-12-30 11:03:38 |            7|
|     5 |    1 | 20788 | 1899-12-30 11:03:45 |            7|
|     6 |    1 | 20789 | 1899-12-30 11:03:52 |         NULL|
|     7 |    2 | 50790 | 1899-12-30 11:04:09 |           17|
|     8 |    2 | 50791 | 1899-12-30 11:04:26 |           61|
|     9 |    2 | 50792 | 1899-12-30 11:05:27 |           11|
|    10 |    2 | 50793 | 1899-12-30 11:05:38 |         NULL|
+-------+------+-------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Where f_rec is Primary Key and f_id a session id.

I would like to create a table with the time difference in seconds between the next record and current for a total of >500 000 records in the table, however the MySQL server (DigitalOcean droplet scaled up to 16GB ) hangs on this query. When I run the SELEct query by itself, it shows me the results fine.

**Question1:** As soon as I either INSERT INTO or CREATE TABLE before the code, the server hangs. I have therefore no option to export this table, which is very fustrating. What am I doing wrong?

**Question2:** I have also looked into user variables and JOINS, where I would love to apply user variables, but cannot get the logic right and JOINS give me similar results. I used examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794061/mysql-time-difference-between-rows-of-the-same-type?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952106/time-difference-among-end-dates-of-first-records-to-next-record-first-dates). How do I do this?

What am I doing wrong, or how can I optimise this?

Comment: What is this column called `REF` you mention in `WHERE IDfocNext.REF = IDfocCurr.REF + 1 `?  Please edit your question to give a precise definition of what you mean by *next record*.

Comment: I'm sorry, the column REF was used in a previous query where i had to identify the (focal) sessions unique id (f_id) and thought it would be useful here as it has been sorted on date (not shown in this sample dataset) and thereafter REF. In other words, the REF will jump with more than 1 if it goes to the next focal session.

Comment: when the jump in REF is more than one, do you still want the difference in ori_time to show between those two records?

Comment: No, i have added desired results to the question. A jump of more than 1 should throw out a NULL in duration as this is a different "session" in my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table has 500,000 records, this query is going to run the inner select for each of them, so a possible combination of 250,000,000,000 (250 billion reads).  No wonder it hangs up.

Try setting a variable and then using it to subtract from, something like this

```
set @lasttime := date(0);
set @lastref := -20;
set @lastfrec := 0;
set @lastfid := 0;
select @lastref as this_ref, @lastfrec as this_frec, @lastfid as this_f_id,
       if (ref - @lastref == 1, timestampdiff(second, @lasttime, IDfocCurr.ori_time, null) as duration_new,
       @lasttime := IDfocCurr.ori_time as this_ori_time,
       @lastfrec := IDfocCurr.f_rec as next_frec,
       @lastfid := IDfocCurr.f_id as next_f_id,
       @lastref := ref as next_ref
from IDfocals1999-2004 IDfocCurr
order by IDfocCurr.f_rec
```

or try this...

```
set @lasttime := null;
set @lastref := -20;
select * from (
select f_rec, f_id, REF, ORI_TIME, if(@lastref - REF = 1, timestampdiff(second, ORI_TIME, @lasttime), null) as duration_new,
       @lasttime := ORI_TIME as next_ori_time,
       @lastref := ref as next_ref
from IDfocals19992004
order by REF DESC) revorder order by REF asc
```

Comment: This is very useful, I'm having a steep learning curve. How do you mean an inner select? 
Your query runs beautifully, however I get a result where the duration will only show one record down. ie. between `f_rec` 1 and 2 is 9 seconds difference, I would like this in duration_new on `f_rec` 1. I'll add a desired result section in my question

Comment: Not entirely clear what you mean in that comment.  Do you mean that the duration between f_rec 1 and 2 is showing on 2, and you want it to show on 1?  If so, do you mind if we sort the results by IDfocCurr.REF DESC.

Comment: I want to sort by `f_rec` and get a `NULL
Yes the duration between 1 and 2 is using your query showing on record 2, where I would like it on record 1. As for our research this is the duration of the trait that is linked to record 1.

Comment: Ok, I've edited accordingly - something like this should work.  It will be more efficient than a join as it will only read through the records once and not try to do any cross-matching (joining each record with another).  All operations in memory.  But I can't test cause no data, so you may have to clean it up.

Comment: regarding your question about the inner select, look at the query in your original posting.  It has a select where one of the items read is another select.  That is a select within a select.  That means that for every record in the outer query, it then has to do a select, the inner one.  If the data is not indexed by that REF, then for every record in the outer query (all 500,000) it then has to again read through all 500,000 to find the match.  the result is a dreadful crossproduct that brings your db server down to its knees.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me an exact same result, with `f_rec` = 1 having a `duration_new` of NULL and `f_rec`=2 a `duration_new` of 9

Comment: that should have given you two values for f_rec, the old and the new, you'd just have to use the previous one.  But let me edit it to make it easier.

Comment: Please let me add (sorry for leaving this out), that I have another 26 columns to this dataset that I want to select out. These would have to move all relatively down if the second f_rec is moving one down. Sounds like I'm making a mess....

Comment: Ok running this query gets me for `this_frec` and `this_f_id` a `[BLOB - 1B]` a new error to me.
Also, the time records, if we move down the f_rec with one, will not be corresponding to the new f_rec anymore.

Comment: I have built a table with your data and am testing a solution that will be simpler

Comment: I understand your system, and it works with the edits I've put in your answer. I just have to stop being a noob and make the full use of RDBMS. I would be able to join back the data using f_rec. Although nog as neat, maybe a solution?

Comment: look at my edits now.  I made it work.  I added a second option in my answer that is simpler but works.  Uses the order by ref desc, but then does another query to put it back in the order you want.  This will take a little more time, but not much more (does not do a cross product).  And it only requires two variables.

Comment: Unfortunately your edit is hanging for the past 10 minutes. I'll let it go for a bit more. Could I send you a subset of my data somehow? Thanks a million for your help so far!

Comment: The major problem with using REF as a sorting factor is that it has duplicates in it. This is where I used REF only after sorting it on the date field, group and animal id field (foolishly not shown in the example), added f_rec in as a unique ID and primary key. This makes when working on the sorted data the next record to a new session (ie. new f_id) always a jump in REF > 1

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are doing an nested select for each row you find, that's going to take a really long time. The reason you find the query fast enough when doing just the select is that it will just return the first couple of rows.

Try doing a normal (self) join instead.

```
select id1.f_rec, 
       id1.f_id,
       id1.ref,
       timestampdiff(second, id1.ori_time, id2.ori_time)
from IDfocals id1
join IDfocals id2 on (id1.f_id = id2.f_id + 1 and id1.f_id = id2.f_id)
```

Comment: Its running as we speak, however it is taking already >5 minutes, so don't know if this is going to work.

Comment: After your last edits the query need to change some. Try these changes. To get the null-values you need to change this into a `left join` and some condition on the timestampdiff-function to show null in some cases.